# Erro ao atualizar entradas no Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Tenho o seguinte código para mapeamento da minha aplicação, mas quando vou tentar fazer um `insert` dá o seguinte erro.

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details

Já tive esse erro anteriormente troquei apenas um `HasOptional` por um `HasRequired` e deu certo mas dessa vez não estou encontrando uma solução para esse erro.

Classe:

```
public partial class REGISTRO_PERGUNTAS
{
    public REGISTRO_PERGUNTAS()
    {
        this.REGISTRO_RESPOSTAS = new List<REGISTRO_RESPOSTAS>();
    }

    public decimal ID_PERGUNTA { get; set; }
    public int ID_ARQUIVO { get; set; }
    public byte ID_TIPO { get; set; }
    public int? NUMERO_PERGUNTA { get; set; }
    public string PERGUNTA { get; set; }
    public string USUARIO_PERGUNTA { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ID_AREA { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DT_PERGUNTA { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SITUACAO { get; set; }
    public virtual AREAS_RESPONSAVEIS AREAS_RESPONSAVEIS { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<REGISTRO_RESPOSTAS> REGISTRO_RESPOSTAS { get; set; }
    public virtual REGISTRO_QUESTIONARIO REGISTRO_QUESTIONARIO { get; set; }
    public virtual TIPOS_PERGUNTA TIPOS_PERGUNTA { get; set; }
}
```

Mapeamento:

```
public class REGISTRO_PERGUNTASMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<REGISTRO_PERGUNTAS>
{
    public REGISTRO_PERGUNTASMap() {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID_PERGUNTA);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.PERGUNTA).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(300);
        this.Property(t => t.USUARIO_PERGUNTA).HasMaxLength(50);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("REGISTRO_PERGUNTAS");
        this.Property(t => t.ID_PERGUNTA).HasColumnName("ID_PERGUNTA");
        this.Property(t => t.ID_ARQUIVO).HasColumnName("ID_ARQUIVO");
        this.Property(t => t.ID_TIPO).HasColumnName("ID_TIPO");
        this.Property(t => t.NUMERO_PERGUNTA).HasColumnName("NUMERO_PERGUNTA");
        this.Property(t => t.PERGUNTA).HasColumnName("PERGUNTA");
        this.Property(t => t.USUARIO_PERGUNTA).HasColumnName("USUARIO_PERGUNTA");
        this.Property(t => t.ID_AREA).HasColumnName("ID_AREA");
        this.Property(t => t.DT_PERGUNTA).HasColumnName("DT_PERGUNTA");
        this.Property(t => t.SITUACAO).HasColumnName("SITUACAO");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.AREAS_RESPONSAVEIS)
            .WithMany(t => t.REGISTRO_PERGUNTAS)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ID_AREA);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.REGISTRO_QUESTIONARIO)
            .WithMany(t => t.REGISTRO_PERGUNTAS)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ID_ARQUIVO);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.TIPOS_PERGUNTA)
            .WithMany(t => t.REGISTRO_PERGUNTAS)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ID_TIPO);
    }
}
```

Comment: Estou sim. Usando ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @Rabelos Segue a sugestão da mensagem de erro e posta a *inner exception*.

Comment: O erro que dá é este "Não é possível inserir um valor explícito para a coluna de identidade na tabela 'REGISTRO_PERGUNTAS' quando IDENTITY_INSERT está definido como OFF"

Comment: @Tiago Silva esse é o meu problema não estou inserindo a PK mas o erro continua. Pesquisando pela net vi outras pessoas com o mesmo problema mas ninguém reportou alguma correção.

Comment: Acrescente à pergunta o conteúdo do "Inner Exception"

Comment: O problema realmente era o tipo do campo o Entity aparentemente  não aceita o tipo numeric na PK. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.

Answer (score 5):

Inclua no seu contexto um `override` para o evento `SaveChanges` da seguinte forma:

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {          
        try
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors) // <-- Coloque um Breakpoint aqui para conferir os erros de validação.
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entidade do tipo \"{0}\" no estado \"{1}\" tem os seguintes erros de validação:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Erro: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.Entries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entidade do tipo \"{0}\" no estado \"{1}\" tem os seguintes erros de validação:",
                    eve.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.State);
            }
            throw;
        }
        catch (SqlException s) {
            Console.WriteLine("- Message: \"{0}\", Data: \"{1}\"",
                        s.Message, s.Data);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Você pode colocar um breakpoint como sugerido ou então verificar as mensagens enviadas para o Console.