# Erro ao atualizar as entradas Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Estou tentando inserir uns dados de uns arquivos pelo entity, porem fica dando esse erro:

Metodo:

```
internal void AddArquivo(Model.Arquivo arquivo)
    {
        using (var ctx = new TESTEntities())
        {
            var versao = arquivo.ArquivoVersoes[0];
            ctx.ARQUIVO.Add(new ARQUIVO()
            {
                ARQUIVO_GUID = arquivo.ARQUIVO_GUID,
                ARQUIVO_VERSAO = new ARQUIVO_VERSAO()
                {
                    ARQUIVO_GUID = arquivo.ARQUIVO_GUID,
                    ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = versao.ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID,
                    ARQUIVO = versao.ARQUIVO,
                    DATAHORA = versao.DATAHORA,
                    TAMANHO = versao.TAMANHO,
                    USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID = versao.USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID
                },
                DIRETORIO_GUID = arquivo.DIRETORIO_GUID,
                EXTENSAO = arquivo.EXTENSAO,
                IS_STREAM = arquivo.IS_STREAM,
                TAG = arquivo.TAG,
                TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID = arquivo.TipoDeArquivo.TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID,
                ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = arquivo.ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID,
                URL = arquivo.URL,
                XARQUIVO = arquivo.XARQUIVO
            });
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}


ERRO: "Erro ao atualizar as entradas. Consulte a exceção interna para obter detalhes."
```

lembrando que minhas chaves primarias estao como varchar, e não sao identity

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException was caught HResult=-2146233087 Message=Erro ao atualizar as entradas. Consulte a exceção interna para obter detalhes. Source=EntityFramework StackTrace: em     
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() em InnerException: 
System.Data.UpdateException HResult=-2146233087 Message=Erro ao atualizar as entradas. Consulte a exceção interna para obter detalhes. Source=System.Data.Entity StackTrace: em 
System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter) em 
System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options) em 
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() InnerException: 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException HResult=-2146232060 Message=Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'ARQUIVO_VERSAO_PK'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object TEST.ARQUIVO_VERSAO'. The statement has been terminated. Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider ErrorCode=-2146232060 Class=14 LineNumber=1 Number=2627 Procedure="" Server=192.168.10.59 State=1 StackTrace: em 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) em 
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) em 
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) em 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) em 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) em 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) em 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() em 
System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues) em 
System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter) InnerException:
```

Comment: Você sobre-escreveu o `OnModelCreating` do `GEDEntities`? Pode ser um erro de validação. Caso contrário, vc precisa ir nos `InnerException` para ver o que aconteceu, se mesmo assim não for detalhado o suficiente, tente isto para mostrar a fundo os erros ocorridos: http://blogs.infosupport.com/improving-dbentityvalidationexception/

Comment: Qual o erro? Pode por favor colocá-lo na sua pergunta?

Comment: Não sobrescrevi o OnModelCreating isso seria oq?

Comment: @WarLock, neste caso é importante posta a InnerException, ou seja a que realmente contem informação util sobre o erro.
Porem se tratando de Entity Framework, vou pedir para você fazer um try com 2 catch, um para DbEntityValidationException e outro para Exception.

Comment: Como vejo esse innerexception?

Comment: Coloquei um catch para DbEntityValidationException, porem no debug ele ja vai para o exception

Comment: Coloque um breakpoint na Excessão, e expanda ela até obter a excessão mais interna.

Comment: vou postar o erro completo

Comment: um exemplo de como pegar uma InnerException: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9CMNuR

Comment: postei o erro...

Comment: Cannot insert duplicate key in object TEST.ARQUIVO_VERSAO'. The statement has been terminated.
Você está tentando inserir uma Chave duplicada no Banco.

Comment: [Nesta resposta ensino a capturar uma exceção interna de contexto usando Entity Framework](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38175/2999).

Comment: esse erro esta no metodo que postei?

Comment: @WarLock Qual a chave primária de `ArquivoVersao`?

Comment: @WarLock, poderia repostar o diagrama das entidades?

Comment: ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID é a PK, postei o diagrama

Comment: postando uma resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro é bastante claro:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException HResult=-2146232060 Message=Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'ARQUIVO_VERSAO_PK'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object TEST.ARQUIVO_VERSAO'. The statement has been terminated.
```

Significa que aqui:

```
            ARQUIVO_VERSAO = new ARQUIVO_VERSAO()
            {
                ARQUIVO_GUID = arquivo.ARQUIVO_GUID,
                ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = versao.ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID, // Isto já existe no banco
                ARQUIVO = versao.ARQUIVO,
                DATAHORA = versao.DATAHORA,
                TAMANHO = versao.TAMANHO,
                USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID = versao.USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID
            },
```

O certo seria você gerar um `Guid` novo para cada nova versão inserida. Como a coluna é `String`, ainda precisa mais uma conversão:

```
            ARQUIVO_VERSAO = new ARQUIVO_VERSAO()
            {
                ARQUIVO_GUID = arquivo.ARQUIVO_GUID,
                ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                ARQUIVO = versao.ARQUIVO,
                DATAHORA = versao.DATAHORA,
                TAMANHO = versao.TAMANHO,
                USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID = versao.USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID
            },
```

Comment: ops, da erro de conversão pra string

Comment: converti, vou testar

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, por alguma razão ele salva e manipula Guids como texto, apenas não me pergunte o por que.

Comment: funcionou valeu ...

Comment: ta dando outro exception do entity, devo criar outro topico?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, o unico problema que vejo nesta resposta, é que você está descartando a PK que está no Arquivo.
Se este for algum programa de integração ou conciliação, isto pode razer muitos problemas.

Comment: @WarLock Deve sim. É outro problema agora.

Comment: tbm percebi isso TOby, porem no momento isso solucionou, e acho que não vou ter problemas em relação a isso.

Comment: @TobyMosque Eu não sei o que faz a lógica dele. Pra resposta isso não parece ser importante.

Comment: @WarLock, este "acho" me passou uma impressão de que lhe falta um entendimento do projeto como um todo, no seu lugar procuraria o arquiteto deste sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando inserir um objeto ARQUIVO_VERSAO que já existe, neste caso é preciso verificar se o mesmo já existe no Banco de Dados.
Você pode faze-lo da seguinte forma:

```
using (var ctx = new TESTEntities())
{
    var versaoAux = arquivo.ArquivoVersoes[0];
    var versao = ctx.ARQUIVO_VERSAO.Find(versaoAux.ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID);
    if (versao == default(ARQUIVO_VERSAO)) 
    {       
        versao = new ARQUIVO_VERSAO()
        {
            ARQUIVO_GUID = arquivo.ARQUIVO_GUID,
            ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = versaoAux.ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID,
            ARQUIVO = versaoAux.ARQUIVO,
            DATAHORA = versaoAux.DATAHORA,
            TAMANHO = versaoAux.TAMANHO,
            USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID = versaoAux.USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID
        };
    }

    ctx.ARQUIVO.Add(new ARQUIVO()
    {
        ARQUIVO_GUID = arquivo.ARQUIVO_GUID,
        ARQUIVO_VERSAO = versao,
        DIRETORIO_GUID = arquivo.DIRETORIO_GUID,
        EXTENSAO = arquivo.EXTENSAO,
        IS_STREAM = arquivo.IS_STREAM,
        TAG = arquivo.TAG,
        TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID = arquivo.TipoDeArquivo.TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID,
        ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = arquivo.ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID,
        URL = arquivo.URL,
        XARQUIVO = arquivo.XARQUIVO
    });
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```