# Erro de validação no entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

No meu método de adicionar arquivos ta dando a seguinte exception ao debugar:

Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Método:

```
  internal void AddArquivo(Model.Arquivo arquivo)
    {
        using (var ctx = new TESTEntities())
        {
            var versao = arquivo.ArquivoVersoes[0];
            ctx.ARQUIVO.Add(new ARQUIVO()
            {
                ARQUIVO_GUID = arquivo.ARQUIVO_GUID,
                ARQUIVO_VERSAO = new ARQUIVO_VERSAO()
                {
                    ARQUIVO_GUID = arquivo.ARQUIVO_GUID,
                    ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    ARQUIVO = versao.ARQUIVO,
                    DATAHORA = versao.DATAHORA,
                    TAMANHO = versao.TAMANHO,
                    USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID = versao.USUARIO_PESSOA_GUID
                },
                DIRETORIO_GUID = arquivo.DIRETORIO_GUID,
                EXTENSAO = arquivo.EXTENSAO,
                IS_STREAM = arquivo.IS_STREAM,
                TAG = arquivo.TAG,
                TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID = arquivo.TipoDeArquivo.TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID,
                ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID = arquivo.ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID,
                URL = arquivo.URL,
                XARQUIVO = arquivo.XARQUIVO
            });
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Já implementou isto?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38175/2999)

Comment: @WarLock, você precisar de um catch com um DbEntityValidationException, tem um exelente exemplo postado pelo Cigano:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38119/erro-ao-atualizar-entradas-no-entity-framework/38175#38175

Comment: Consegui , era no contexto do meu projeto, onde tinha GUID.neGuid.ToString() assim ele gera um GUid aleatorio com caracteres, e no meu contexto nao aceitava, dai usei uma biblioteca q ja tem pronta no projeto, que formada da forma correta, Util.Util.GUIDs.GetGUID(),

Comment: @TobyMosque da uma olhada no outro topico que criei, valeu.