# Exceção DbUpdateException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, code-first

Estou tentado estudar EF com Code First. Estou recebendo esta exceção no `SaveChanges()`

An unhandled exception of type System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.**DbUpdateException** occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Outro problema seria quando tento criar outra classe para servir como tabela, recebo uma exceção chamada `InvalidOperationException` segue a stack trace

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: The model backing the 'SchoolContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Comment: Estou conseguindo criar o banco, mas não estou conseguindo inserir dados nele.

Comment: [Sua pergunta já tem resposta aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38119/erro-ao-atualizar-entradas-no-entity-framework/38175#38175), mas marquei a duplicata errado. Veja se te atende.

Comment: Engraçado! Estava estudando por aqui : [http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx]. Comentei algumas `Properties` da classe `Student` e rodou!

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez É uma abordagem bem interessante!! Adorei sua resposta. Mas tenho outro problema, quando tento criar outra classe recebo no contexto `ctx.Professores.Add(prof)` recebo uma exceçao An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: The model backing the 'SchoolContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database ([http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269]).

Comment: Edite sua resposta colocando este novo erro (não apague o texto anterior) que respondo pra você.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para este erro:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The model backing the 'SchoolContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Você mapeou os *Models* mas não gerou a variação incremental do banco, chamada *Migration*. Para gerar uma *Migration* abra o Package Manager Console (View > Other Windows > Package Manager Console) e digite:

```
PM> Add-Migration NomeDaMigration
```

Isto irá gerar um arquivo com as modificações que deverão ser feitas no banco. Feito isso, digite agora:

```
PM> Update-Database
```

Isto irá atualizar seu banco de dados com as modificações feitas em seus *Models*. Feito isso, basta executar sua aplicação.

---

Se aparecer este erro:

> No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'School'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration)

No Package Manager Console, digite:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
```

Aguarde o Visual Studio configurar seu projeto, depois repita os passos para gerar sua *Migration* novamente:

```
PM> Add-Migration Inicial
PM> Update-Database
```

Comment: Obrigado novamente pela ótima explicação. Realmente estou aprendendo muito! Mas ainda estou com erros... Quando digito `Add-Migration NomeDaMigration` recebo isso "No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'School'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration)".

Comment: Ah, sim. Vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: @tek6 Veja agora.

Comment: Milhões de Obrigados pra vc! Resolveu meu problema e, ainda, me ensinou o básico de EF Code First! @ciganomorrisonmendez